# 2017 Election Results: Congratulations to the new moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The [2017 elections](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/6) are over. By analyzing the [OpaSTV file](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/6) with the voting data, the result of the 2017 moderator elections are as follows (with no particular order):

[image: quid]
[image: Jack D'Aurizio]

In the name of all the users on Mathematics SE, congratulations on your victory!

You can [view a summary report of the election](https://www.opavote.com/results/4828042769727488/0) on OpaVote.

Also, today we bid farewell to [arjafi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8348/arjafi), who is stepping down after 4 years as a moderator. Please join me in thanking him for his tireless service to the Mathematics community.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations to both of you!

Comment: I'm astounded by your speed, and indeed I think you had Jon beat as well. But I think it's confusing to have multiple open, and I've decided to keep the community team's as the primary one. Sorry!

Comment: Congrats! Here's one user who's happy with the result!

Comment: In previous years my thread was just made the official one... :)

Comment: You know, you're right. I declare you the winner afterall. Incoming merge.

Comment: Thanks arjafi, for all the hours spent keeping MSE a nice and hospitable place!

Comment: Thanks arjafi.  I wish you were sticking around.  Really I do. It won't ever be the same without you!

Comment: Congrats! I'm really happy to see that D'Aurizio is a new moderator of MSE! :)

Comment: @Shog: Thanks for the upgrade with the sad notice about arjafi. He will be sorely missed.

Comment: (P.S. I don't think I could beat the 25 seconds record next time. But I guess we'll have to wait and see.)

Comment: Congratulations to all !!!

Comment: good try @tatan

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @dp1611 Have you seen the ballots? I lost in the second round only...;-9

Comment: @amWhy: I agree that it is a good idea to separate the leaving mods from the coming mods, but traditionally these were announced together. This time, however, the identity of the leaving moderator was not publicly revealed before this edit.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Asaf. I appreciate it; (and thanks for catching my question before I deleted it)!  I'm just sad/discouraged about arjafi leaving us; and there's likely no "best practice" for announcing the stepping-down of an awesome mod.

Comment: @amWhy Why did you not go for moderation? I thought you may fancy it. Or is it just that I (and a few others) think every reputed member fancies it? I mean, it is a coveted job, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  I've already got my hands full trying to help the site (largely janitorial work), quality-control and to keep big-wigs, including mods, in check.

Comment: @amWhy Suppose like arjafi, you would like to step down (if you can) from quality control and such work, then how would you communicate this, and find replacements, if any, because sometimes having your hands full with janitorial work does not allow you to focus on the mathematical aspect on this site, and I feel that this will be disturbing for you. Furthermore, your "sweeping" work goes under the carpet as compared to moderation, so nobody notices your work. I appreciate it all the same, having seen your participation on meta sites.

Comment: Yes, @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  I would like to get back to answering questions a bit more than I do right now.  But for four years I was immersed in answering.  While others were working hard to maintain the site that allowed me to answer so many questions. So I've committed the last year and a half to helping maintain the site's quality, continuing to review, edit, contribute, but in less "notorious" ways.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for your selfless service to this site. I hope I go down your path sometime in the future.

Comment: Congrats to the new moderators :)

Comment: Congratulations to both of you! Thank you for your service.

Comment: Congratulations to new Mods. All the best :D

Comment: congratulations to all who elected. Hope you make the desirable results for the community. I believe this community deserves best moderation and thrive.

Comment: Congratulations!!!

Comment: @mixedmath: If I recall correctly, the featured tag has an auto-expiration of a month. No?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Now that you mention it, you're right. I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: @mixedmath: Yeah, we don't have featured posts usually. So it's completely understandable.

Answer (score 108):

I am very happy to have succeeded in joining the current team of moderators. I am very grateful towards anyone that has supported me and I wish to carry on a good job as a moderator.

Love you all!

Comment: I am really happy you were elected. Your comments and answers are always of great mathematical value... I hope you will keep answering questions on the site...

Comment: I seriously thought you will not be elected. I he main reason was *people like me were worried that if elected you will get busy in closing/reopening/editing sort of things and hence won't give much time to add good content on site and will be engaged in improving the content which is already in the site*. But as now you are elected, I hope as a student who prefer to learn from MSE over other sites I hope we will not be deprived of classic Jack D' Aurizio techniques and extraordinary answering abilities. Congratulations BTW . :-P

Comment: @Isham: Not to be *that guy*, but having comments and answers with great mathematical value has little to nothing with moderating the site. If anything, moderators often find themselves spending less time on mathematics. That being said, good luck Jack!

Comment: Well @AsafKaragila I agree with you  but what do we know about the candidates ? Their writings on mathematics the pedagogy they show all that... And this site is about mathematics so it require to be qualified to know what is a good answer and what is not...I voted for Jack even though I prefer to see him solving poblems and sharing his vast knowledge.

Comment: @Isham: This is why it is better to be involved with the meta site before the elections. Candidates are encouraged to interact with people and voice their opinions and ideas about meta-topics, and prospective voters can better know these people. This is why I usually prefer to vote to people who are more active on meta; and would not object to limit voting rights to people with more active meta history (at least in reading)...

Comment: @AsafKaragila   Maybe you are right..I know most of the candidates by their comments and answers posted on the mathematic side of the site not on meta. I do read meta from time toi time.

Comment: @Isham comments and answers on the main site are only half the story.  It's all good and well, but it's not necessarily enough.  Mods need to be balanced: focusing on the bigger picture, not just on answering.  I trust Jack can do this; but just recognize that being talented in math and showing it time and again doesn't make a moderator.  Other qualities and strengths and focus are likely more important.  In any case, I agree with Asaf, but I also trust that Jack will rise to the occasion.

Comment: @amWhy I said that I agree with asaf about that. And i do agree with you too. But still there are more in an answer than it looks. Some people are pedagogic they take time to answer and they do that politely with no arrogance even when the question is asked and lacks formatting and editing.. They take time to answer even basic questions...So you can deduce lots of things even though the answer is just about mathematics...It's my first election too..I don't know most people.

Comment: @Isham Stick around, and you'll get to know people, mostly great people, but including some you might feel you'd rather not know! :)  Thanks for your participation in this year's election, and your votes! What you find important for users/mods on this site matters a lot. And it will be great if you stick around for another election, or more, down the road.

Comment: Congrats Jack!  you deserve it.

Comment: I was concerned it may be away to duller ? mod type work. But anyway, Congratulations, Jack!

Comment: If its not against the policies or something undisclosable can I know why Jack is no longer the mod?

Comment: @tatan I think he just resigned a few months ago.

Comment: @ArnaudD. He was a very competent and deserving fellow. Why did he leave? Any idea? (PS. I am not unnecesarily trying to poke my nose.. just curious ;-) )

Answer (score 78):

I want to use this opportunity to give my personal thanks to @arjafi.
He leaves a huge void in the moderator team. Filling it up will take a long while and requires growth and learning from both the existing and the newly elected moderators. Arthur's expertise on how the site works from diamond bearers' perspective is second to none.

I don't know if I'm a good moderator or not, but I do know that having arjafi around, giving advice, discussing problematic cases, whatnot, has made me a much better moderator than what I would be under my own steam. Lately most of his work was largely invisible. This saddens me, but such is life.

> **Arjafi: Thanks for everything! Welcome back any time you feel like it!**

Also: Congrats to Jack & quid (in no particular order). Impressive vote tallies, both of you!

Comment: Hear hear! Having had the pleasure to meet arjafi on several occasions, I can say that it is a true loss for the site.

Comment: @Jyrki "I don't know if I'm a good moderator or not ..."  *You are a great mod!*  You'd be impossible to replace, and I'm quite sure that an awful lot of folks feel the same.  It's also true that arjafi can't be replaced.  Here's a cheer to the new mods, and hoping they also find their irreplaceable niche as a mod.

Comment: I really wonder who downvoted this post.@AsafKaragila By meet, did you mean in person or in online chats?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Probably meant on the main site and/or meta?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: We had a few beers on a few occasions. And sort of shared an office for two weeks once.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Speculating about a downvote is fun but futile. 1) It may be because I drew a bit of attention to my person (surely misplaced in this thread). I just wanted to give a glimpse to the extent of the invisible ways Arthur has been helping the site. 2) It may be because somebody just disproves of Arthur's moderation. Whatever, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Jyrki, have no doubt, you are a ***great*** moderator!  Thanks for all you have done here.  Best wishes and, of course, Cheers!